# Sending a file via UDT, increasing the buffersize will break my code

Tags: c++, c, file, networking, buffer

I am trying to send a file with UDT, its UDP with congestion control and all that stuff TCP normally provides. I also know that there is a sendfile method in the UDT libary, but I would like to try it myself. A buffer with the size 1024 or 512 seems to work, but when I increase it to 2048 for example, the recvfile buffer loop sometimes gets stuck or the file is transmitted incorrectly. And it's stuck really randomly, some iterations before it finishes and it should go on beacuse the filesize is still bigger than the buffersize.

```
bool sendfile(UDTSOCKET socket, char* filepath, unsigned int buffsize)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "rb");
    unsigned long filesize;
    char filesizec[20];
    char* filename;
    char* buffer;

    if (file == NULL)
    {
         cout << "error: file " << filepath << " not found" << endl;
         return false;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    filesize = ftell(file);
    filename =  basename(filepath);
    sprintf(filesizec, "%ld", filesize);

    if (UDT::send(socket, filename, 255, 0) == ERROR ||
        UDT::send(socket, filesizec, 20, 0) == ERROR)
    {
       cout << "sendfile error: " << getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
       return false;
    }

    rewind(file);

    if (filesize < 0)
        return false;

    buffer = (char*) malloc(buffsize * sizeof(char));
    do
    {
        if (filesize >= buffsize)
        {
            if(fread(buffer, 1, buffsize, file) != buffsize)
                cout << "error reading file: " << filepath << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if(fread(buffer, 1, filesize, file) != filesize)
                cout << "error reading file: " << filepath << endl;
            filesize = 0;
            if (UDT::send(socket, buffer, buffsize, 0) == ERROR)
            {
                cout << "sendfile error: " << getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (UDT::send(socket, buffer, buffsize, 0) == ERROR)
        {
            cout << "sendfile error: " << getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
            return false;
        }
        filesize -= buffsize;
    }
    while (filesize > 0);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return true;
}

bool recvfile (UDTSOCKET socket, unsigned int buffsize)
{
    FILE *file;
    char* buffer;
    char filename[255];
    char filesizec[20];
    unsigned long filesize;

    if (UDT::recv(socket, filename, 255, 0) == UDT::ERROR ||
        UDT::recv(socket, filesizec, 20, 0) == UDT::ERROR)
    {
        cout << "recv:" << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage() << endl;
        return false;
    }
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    filesize = atol(filesizec);
    cout << "incoming file: " << filename << " " << filesize << endl;

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        cout << "error: cannot create file:" << file << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (filesize < 0)
        return false;

    buffer = (char*) malloc(buffsize * sizeof(char));
    do
    {
        if (UDT::recv(socket, buffer, buffsize, 0) == UDT::ERROR)
        {
            cout << "recvfile error: " << getlasterror().getErrorMessage();
            return false;
        }
        if (filesize >= buffsize)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, buffsize, file);
            filesize -= buffsize;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(buffer, 1, filesize, file);
            filesize = 0;
            break;
        }

    }
    while (filesize > 0);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ethernet packets are about 1500 bytes, so sending 2048 bytes means sending two packets, whereas 1024 and 512 fit into one packet.

Comment: Well, if I use a buffersize of 1025 and not 1024, it does not work. So, I dont know if its about the ethernet package size.